# invalid syntax changing python file permission with chmod +x

Tags: python, python3

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
chmod +x let.py
import sys
```

top 3 lines of program above then when I try to run ./let.py it will give me this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc7Rv.png) I am not sure why this isn't working

Comment: Uuuhm, chmod is no python command.

Comment: to use python code to set permissions, see answer.

Answer (score 1):

This command is an **sh** command. Type exit() to exit python and then you can type `chmod +x let.py`

Comment: oh okay I got it working now.  ty!

Answer (score 1):

#### Changing file permissions from python

As mentioned in a comment, just `chmod` is not a python command. Not sure which file you are trying to change permissions of, but do do that from python code, you've got two options:

1. Use `os.chmod`:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import os

   # use 0o (zero + "o" before 755 to use octal)   
   os.chmod('/path/to/file.py', 0o755)
   ```
2. Use `subprocess`:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess

   subprocess.Popen(["chmod", "+x", "/path/to/file.py"])
   ```

#### Note:

For shebang, `#!/usr/bin/env python3` is saver than `#!/usr/bin/python3`, which might break on other distros.